# 'DecisionTreeClassifier' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pipeline

I try to visualize a decision tree after a pipeline.

Here is my code:

```
num_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('impute', SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')),
    ('scale', MinMaxScaler())
])
cat_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('impute', SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')),
    ('one-hot',OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False))
])


from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('num_pipeline',num_pipeline,num_cols),
    ('cat_pipeline',cat_pipeline,cat_cols)
    ],
    remainder='drop',
    n_jobs=-1)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import tree

clf = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('classifier', tree.DecisionTreeClassifier())
])

from sklearn import metrics

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
# preds = clf_pipeline.predict(X_test)
model = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print(f"Model score: {model}") # accuracy

tree.plot_tree(clf['classifier'])
```

But, I get a error which is: TypeError: 'DecisionTreeClassifier' object is not subscriptable.

How can I fix it?

I think everything is done properly but I still get the error, and I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Please include code that has all required imports and data sample that could be easily run by others. By not providing them you make it hard for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try

```
tree.plot_tree(clf)
```

Or maybe

```
tree.plot_tree(clf.named_steps['classifier'])
```

?

The error says that `clf` object cannot be accessed with `['something']` notation.